# For a np.array([1, 2, 3]) why is the shape (3,) instead of (3,1)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I noticed that for a rank 1 array with 3 elements numpy returns (3,) for the shape. I know that this tuple represents the size of the array along each dimension, but why isn't it (3,1)?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])  # Create a rank 1 array
print a.shape            # Prints "(3,)"

b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])   # Create a rank 2 array
print b.shape                     # Prints "(2, 3)"
```

Comment: One set of brackets, one dimension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a nutshell, this is because it's *one*-dimensional array (hence the *one*-element shape tuple). Perhaps the following will help clear things up:

```
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3]).shape
(3,)
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3]]).shape
(1, 3)
>>> np.array([[1], [2], [3]]).shape
(3, 1)
```

We can even go three dimensions (and higher):

```
>>> np.array([[[1]], [[2]], [[3]]]).shape
(3, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could equally ask, "Why is the shape not `(3,1,1,1,1,1,1)`?  They are equivalent, after all.

NumPy often chooses to collapse singular dimensions, or treat them as optional, such as during [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  This is powerful because a 3-vector has exactly the same number of elements, and in the same relative orientation, as a 3x1x1x1x1x1 matrix.

Comment: This is incorrect - broadcasting ignores _leading_ dimensions of length 1, not trailing ones. So `1x1x1x1x1x3` is the same as `3`

Comment: `numpy` can add leading 1s during broadcasting, but it does not ignore them, whether leading or trailing.  You have use `squeeze` or indexing to remove them.